# Splitting a json object however its coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to split a json object. The object is coming through to my api. However, when I try to break the object, I get `undefined`.

object:

```
Object {_id: "248mehw32ako48wuwvobf66fvoevb2p", auth: "YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ="}
```

js code

```
server.del('/inter/delete', (req, res) => {
    //From the URL both the auth and listID is extrcted
    console.log('body test')
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log('id te')

    const listID = req.body._id
    console.log(req.body.auth)
    const auth = req.body.auth

    inter.deleWeather(auth, listID, (data) => {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
        res.send(data.code, {status: data.status, message: 'this should delete the specified resource'})
        res.end()
    })
})
```

Comment: What might `inter.deleWeather` do?

Comment: What `console.log(req.body)` display in console?

Comment: Are you using some middleware to parse json? Like `body-parser`? From the code you've provided, I can't figure it out.